# Find a number of occurrences in internal collections in a functional way

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the best way to find a number of occurrences of each element in a functional/Scala way?

```
Seq(Set("a", "b", "c"), Set("b"), Set("b", "c"))
```

As a result, I need something like

```
Set(("a", 1), ("b", 3), ("c", 2))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`flatten`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatten[B]:List[B]) and [`groupBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]):

```
scala> val s = Seq(Set("a", "b", "c"), Set("b"), Set("b", "c"))
s: Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] =
  List(Set(a, b, c), Set(b), Set(b, c))

scala> s.flatten
res0: Seq[String] =
  List(a, b, c, b, b, c)

scala> s.flatten.groupBy(identity)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]] =
  Map(b -> List(b, b, b), a -> List(a), c -> List(c, c))

scala> s.flatten.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.size) }.toSet
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, Int)] =
  Set((b,3), (a,1), (c,2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
scala> val x = Seq(Set("a", "b", "c"), Set("b"), Set("b", "c"))
x: Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = List(Set(a, b, c), Set(b), Set(b, c))
scala> (x.flatten groupBy identity mapValues (_.size)).toSet
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, Int)] = Set((b,3), (a,1), (c,2))
```